# Почему высота вычисляется не правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему так происходит, когда я вычисляю высоту блока, то высота `.wrap` вычисляется как нужно, а высота `.inner` вычисляется без учета `padding` хотя свойство `box-sizing: border-box` установлено.

```js
$(function() {
  
  var heightWrap = $(".wrap").height(),
      heightInner = $(".inner").height();
      
  console.log("height wrap - " + heightWrap);
  console.log("height inner - " + heightInner);
  
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p></p>
  <div class="inner">
    <div>some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

```js
$(function() {
  
  var heightWrap = $(".wrap").height(),
      heightInner = $(".inner").outerHeight();
      
  console.log("height wrap - " + heightWrap);
  console.log("height inner - " + heightInner);
  
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p></p>
  <div class="inner">
    <div>some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD:** Почему высота вычисляется не правильно?

Как сказано в документации [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

> Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.

*Потому что `.height()`всегда возвращает высоту элемента независимо от значения свойства CSS `box-sizing`*

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `.outerHeight()` вместо `height()`

Comment: в чем отличие Вашего ответа ?